# Split String if it has number

Tags: java, android, regex, split

Hi Guys its been a while since I ask another question,

I have this String which consist of a name and a number
Ex.

> String myString = "give11arrow123test2356read809cell1245cable1257give222..."

Now what I am trying to do is to split it whenever there is a number attached to it

I have to split it so that I could have a result like this

> give11, arrow123, test2356, read809, cell1245, cable1257, give222, ....

I could use this code but I cant find the right regex

> String[] arrayString = myString.split("Regex")

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [**lookarounds**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to split your string.

> Lookarounds are zero-width assertions. They don't consume any characters on the string. The point of zero-width is the validation to see if a regex can or cannot be matched looking ahead or looking back from the current position, without adding them to the overall match.

```
String s = "give11arrow123test2356read809cell1245cable1257give222...";
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[give11, arrow123, test2356, read809, cell1245, cable1257, give222, ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex for spliting

```
String regex = "(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with using regex in java, but this expression matches what you need on [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com)

```
([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)
```

Comment: the String.split() function needs a regex to match between the strings that are returned in the String array, so this regex would not work for this purpose.